# El camino para convertirse en un desarrollador de software

Tags: patrones-de-diseño, ingenieria-del-software

Me gustaria saber cual es el camino para convertirse en un desarrollador de software completo y avanzado. Ya se algo de programacion pero quiero saber cual es el camino correcto para llegar a serlo de una manera un poco mas profesional. Les dare unos temas y quisiera que me dijeran que piensan o si pudieran corregir el orden o agregar mas temas.

1. Programacion basica: Aprender un lenguaje y lo basico como if, while, for, funciones, etc.
2. Algoritmos.
3. Limpieza del codigo: Corregir errores al escribir codigo.
4. Programacion Orientada a Objetos.
5. Diseño de Software.

Comment: de hecho el tema de algoritmia debe ir antes de escribir líneas de código en cualquier lenguaje

Comment: Estudia ingenieria en Sistemas.

Comment: Esta pregunta no se ajusta a la temática/formato del sitio dentro del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda, además de ser bastante subjetiva y estar basada principalmente en opiniones. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y el contenido del mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta es algo ámplia, pero para desarrollar software teniendo de guía libros como el ***Pressman***, se debe respetar un ciclo de vida que resumidamente se compone por:

1. Análisis
2. Diseño
3. Codificación
4. Pruebas
5. Implementación

Yo personalmente, opino que para desarrollar software o al menos para ser un profesional completo se debe conocer todas las etapas, aunque el objetivo sea ser un desarrollador software, entender el:

1. **Análisis**: Es útil para intentar comprender lo que realmente se quiere realizar, independientemente de como se realice.
2. **Diseño**: Para encontrar la mejor forma de como realizar algo, una vez que el "algo" ya este definido.
3. **Codificación**: En esta sección, entraría el conocimiento sobre la herramienta (lenguaje de programación).
4. **Pruebas**: Una vez desarrollado el software entender como se pueden constatar que funcione correctamente en todos los escenarios posibles.

Aunque sea aburrido, te recomiendo leer algún libro de Ingeniería de Software para tener un punto inicial en el tema.
Saludos.

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que solicitan opiniones en vez de realidades, o no tratan sobre la programación o el desarrollo como lo definimos en el [help]. Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.